# Bootstrap 3 Datetimepicker not showing in an ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I know this is a common problem, but I have scoured all the other questions and tried all possible solutions.

I'm trying to implement a simple Bootstrap 3 datetimepicker in an MVC 5 application, but can't get it to show. The default browser datepicker works, but when I try to use bootstrap, I get a simple text-box with nothing else.

I used NuGet to download the required packages:

`Install-Package Bootstrap.v3.Datetimepicker.CSS`

This is my model:

```
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [Display(Name = "Due Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:G}",
    ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
```

This is my view:

```
    <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DueDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DueDate, new { @class = "form-control datetimepicker " })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DueDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is my BundleConfig.cs file:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                 "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                 "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css",
                 "~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css",
                 "~/Content/site.css"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/moment").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/moment.js"));
```

This is what I have at the bottom of my view (Index.cs) to start the javascript:

```
@section scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
    });
</script>}
```

Am I missing something?

Any kind of help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: What error are you getting in the browser console (you have not shown where you loading those bundles - the only one you have is `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")`

Comment: You probably forgot to render the bundle you created

Comment: I absolutely did. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had forgotten to render the bundles, so adding `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")`
 solved the issue. Thank you very much Stephen Muecke and Alexander Derc!